# How can I parse through an HTML body to get table data?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm new here and apologize if this question is too simple for most here.  I am using Excel VBA to open a specific email, find the information on a table I need, and send that information back to my Excel spreadsheet. My code has since broke (was working previously) because the email sender decided to format their email differently. I need help revising the code to find the information I need. FYI, I'm not opposed to rewriting my code entirely, I know there is a quicker way.

If it is not explained well in the code, I am just looking for the example table below in the email and retrieving those 3 numbers and placing them into my spreadsheet. That's all.

**Table Example:**

OnHoldMerge/CancellationJob:

```
RXs Canceled        540    
Orders Cancelled    459    
Orders Merged      1035
```

**My current code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import_OnHold_Merge_Job()

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '   This function opens the On Hold/Merge Email from
    '   PSM, copies the three numbers on the OnHoldMerge/
    '   CancellationJob table, and pastes that data in the Trad
    '   workflow file on the provided tab.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '   CONSTANTS
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Const DestinationSheet = "Fairfax Aging" 'Sheet to output report
    Const ReportRow = 19 'The row on Controls tab where this report is found


    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '   VARIABLES
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim lngRowCounter       As Long
    Dim lngColCounter       As Long
    Dim intChartRow         As Integer
    Dim lngLastRow          As Long
    Dim intLastCol          As Integer
    Dim lngDestinationRow   As Long

    Dim strFileName         As String
    Dim strTestFileName     As String
    Dim strErrorMessage     As String

    Dim wkbkReport          As Workbook

    'Outlook Variables
    Dim olOutlook           As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEmail             As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olBody              As String
    Dim olHTMLBody          As String

    Dim elements            As Object
    Dim element             As Object


    'Variables used to parse the html into usable data
    Dim lngTableLocation    As Long
    Dim lngPrevTableStart   As Long
    Dim lngTableStart       As Long
    Dim lngTableEnd         As Long
    Dim strTableText        As String

    Dim lngRowStart         As Long
    Dim lngRowEnd           As Long
    Dim lngColStart         As Long
    Dim lngColEnd           As Long
    Dim lngFindLocation     As Long
    'index 1 = row #, index 2 = col #
    Dim strCellText(1 To 17, 1 To 2) As String

    'Variables used during removal of unwanted text
    Dim lngRemoveStart      As Long
    Dim lngRemoveEnd        As Long


    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '   FUNCTION
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Debug.Print ("Sub Import_OnHold_Merge_Job")

    'Initialize variable
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets("Controls").Select
    Range("C" & ReportRow) = "Running"   'Set current Status
    Range("N" & ReportRow) = Now         'Log start time
    strFileName = Range("D" & ReportRow) 'Get file location/name

    'Disables screen updating to improve speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Find destination area
    Sheets(DestinationSheet).Select
    lngLastRow = Find_Last_Row("A")
    For lngRowCounter = 1 To lngLastRow
        If Cells(lngRowCounter, 1).Value = "IBML" Then
            lngDestinationRow = lngRowCounter
            Exit For 'Row found exit the loop
        End If
    Next lngRowCounter

    'Clear previous values
    Range(Cells(lngDestinationRow + 3, 5), Cells(lngDestinationRow + 5, 5)).Value = ""

    'Initialize outlook
    Set olOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Check if file exists/open file
    On Error GoTo FileOpenError
    Set olEmail = olOutlook.Session.OpenSharedItem(strFileName)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    olEmail.Display

    'Safety Measure to prevent email from being sent to anyone during testing
    olEmail.To = ""
    olEmail.CC = ""
    olEmail.BCC = ""

    'Copy the body of the email
    olHTMLBody = olEmail.HTMLBody

    'Locate the current and previous tables to find the correct table tags
    lngTableLocation = InStr(1, olHTMLBody, "OnHoldMerge/CancellationJob:")
    lngPrevTableStart = InStr(1, olHTMLBody, "Job Name")
    lngTableStart = InStr(lngPrevTableStart, olHTMLBody, "<table")
    lngTableEnd = InStr(lngTableStart, olHTMLBody, "</table>") + 17
    strTableText = VBA.Mid(olHTMLBody, lngTableStart, lngTableEnd - lngTableStart)
    'htmlTestTable = strTableText

    lngFindLocation = 1
    'Identify Rows in table
    For lngRowCounter = 1 To 17
        'Identify Cells in row
        For lngColCounter = 1 To 2

            'Find the start of the inside string
            lngFindLocation = InStr(lngFindLocation, strTableText, "<td")
            lngColStart = lngFindLocation


            'Find the end of the inside string
            lngFindLocation = InStr(lngFindLocation, strTableText, "</td")
            lngColEnd = lngFindLocation

            'Store the inside string
            strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter) = VBA.Mid(strTableText, lngColStart, lngColEnd - lngColStart)

        Next lngColCounter
    Next lngRowCounter

    'Clean up the strings
    For lngRowCounter = 1 To 17
        For lngColCounter = 1 To 2

            'Remove any remaining html tags
            Do While InStr(1, strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter), "<") > 0
                'Find tag start
                lngRemoveStart = InStr(1, strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter), "<")
                'Find tag end
                lngRemoveEnd = InStr(1, strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter), ">") + 1
                'Remove tag
                strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter) = Replace(strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter), _
                VBA.Mid(strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter), lngRemoveStart, lngRemoveEnd - lngRemoveStart), _
                "")
            Loop

            'Remove any remaining html new lines
            Do While InStr(1, strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter), "&nbsp;") > 0
                'Find new line start
                lngRemoveStart = InStr(1, strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter), "&nbsp;")
                'Find new line end
                lngRemoveEnd = lngRemoveStart + 6
                strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter) = Replace(strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter), _
                VBA.Mid(strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter), lngRemoveStart, lngRemoveEnd - lngRemoveStart), _
                "")
            Loop

            'Trim any remaining blank space
            strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter) = VBA.Trim(strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter))

            Debug.Print ("Row " & lngRowCounter & " Col " & lngColCounter & ": " & strCellText(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter))
        Next lngColCounter
    Next lngRowCounter

    'Empty variables that are no longer needed
    olEmail.Close (olDiscard)

    Set olEmail = Nothing
    Set olOutlook = Nothing

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets(DestinationSheet).Select

    'Output Variables
    Cells(lngDestinationRow + 3, 5).Value = strCellText(3, 2)
    Cells(lngDestinationRow + 4, 5).Value = strCellText(4, 2)
    Cells(lngDestinationRow + 5, 5).Value = strCellText(5, 2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

EndProcessing:

    Report_Complete_Processing _
        ReportRow:=ReportRow, _
        reportStatus:="Completed", _
        reportWorkbook:=wkbkReport

    'End sub, process complete
    Exit Sub

FileOpenError:

    strErrorMessage = "Unable to locate the stored email, please enter values manually."

ErrorHandler:

    'Output Error data to debug window
    Debug.Print ("ErrNum: " & Err.Number)
    Debug.Print ("ErrMsg: " & Err.Description)

    'If there was no error message provided then use a generic message.
    If strErrorMessage = "" Then
        strErrorMessage = "There was a problem processing the report."
    End If

    Debug.Print ("Custom ErrMsg: " & strErrorMessage)

    Report_Complete_Processing _
        ReportRow:=ReportRow, _
        reportStatus:="Failed", _
        reportWorkbook:=wkbkReport, _
        reportMessage:=strErrorMessage

End Sub
```

Comment: Loading the message's `HTMLBody` into a `HTMLDocument` object, and then loading the table (represented by `strTableText`) into a `htmlTable` object might reduce the amount of code -- and let you parse it as a document rather than an ordinary string. But this is a secondary issue. The primary issue is why does your current code no longer work. You're looking for a few strings (`OnHoldMerge/CancellationJob:`, `Job Name`) to isolate the table. Are theyno longer present in the message? What about `RXs Canceled`, `Orders Cancelled` and `Orders Merged`, are they still present? Where does it break?

Comment: Can we see example table HTML?

Comment: @QHarr My sincere apologies for not responding back to this question. I went on maternity leave and then was working on resolving this when I was back at work. I resolved this by having the people responsible for sending this email to post the data as a file to a shared drive location. I now use code to find that data that way.

Comment: @chillin too....